# How to initialize parent case class parameters in constructor

Tags: scala

the following code works as intended:

```
scala> case class Family(numPeople: Int)
defined class Family

scala> class MyFamily(val numBoys: Int, val numGirls: Int) extends Family(numBoys + numGirls)
defined class MyFamily

scala> val f = new MyFamily(2, 3)
f: MyFamily = Family(5)

scala> f.numPeople
res5: Int = 5
```

But what if the `numBoys + numGirls` part is more complex and takes several lines, is there some tidy way to set the numPeople value later? I tried doing this, but the `Family(0)` part looks wrong:

```
scala> class MyComplexFamily(val numBoys: Int, val numGirls: Int) extends Family(0) {
     | override val numPeople = numBoys + numGirls
     | }
defined class MyComplexFamily

scala> val f3 = new MyComplexFamily(3, 4)
f3: MyComplexFamily = Family(7)
```

Answer (score 6):

Case class inheritance is, though possible, discouraged - scala compiler generates `equals` and `hashCode` methods for case classes, and if you ever intend to be able to distinguish between a `MyComplexFamily(3, 4)` and `Family(7)`, you're in trouble.

If, however, the only reason for that `MyComplexFamily` to exist is to perform some processing of input data, the preferred approach would be to define alternative constructor in the companion object of the case class.

```
case class Family(numPeople: Int)
object Family {
  def ofBoysAndGirls(numBoys: Int, numGirls: Int): Family = Family(numBoys + numGirls)
}
```

Another way to do that is to extract common features into a trait and extend it in both classes - that way you won't need to initialize parameters.

```
trait Family {
  def numPeople: Int
}
case class Family(numPeople: Int) extends Family
case class ComplexFamily(numBoys: Int, numGirls: Int) extends Family {
  val numPeople = numBoys + numGirls
}
```